# List of singular and plural adjectives. Does the object take singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

Example:

The line has one, both, or neither point.

or

The line has one, both, or neither points.

Comment: Why use _both_ when you can use _two_? And why use _neither_ when you can use _no_?

Comment: It's for math. You can't say two because it isn't as accurate as both. Both implies there are ONLY two. So it can have one, both, or nothing at all.

Comment: _One, two, or nothing at all_ implies there are only two. _Both_ is just a suppletive variant of *_all two_, which doesn't occur in English.

Comment: We have to use these terms in math. If you can help me understand whether the object should use singular or plural, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Don't use _neither_, then. It isn't parallel; use _no points_ instead. And it should be plural.

Comment: Adjectives cannot be plural in English. They also cannot be singular because **adjectives are not marked for number** at all in English. Things like *these students* and *those students* use plural demonstrative determiners not plural adjectives, and things like *professors emeriti* or *professors emeritae* (not to mention *appellations contrôlées, nouveaux arrivés, musicas norteñas, tortillas españolas, uomini universali*) all use non-English plural adjectives, which doesn't count.